# lost ability to connect to tor network

Tags: relays, firefox, network-configuration

I've been using tor and Firefox 40.0.2 for years. I recently updated to Firefox 43.0b9, then to the latest, then back to 43.0b9 and ultimately downgraded again to 40.0.2. Somewhere along the way tor began taking several minutes to connect instead of approximately 10 seconds, and once it connected, websites wouldn't load.

I attempted a tor update and it wouldn't finish, so i deleted tor and reinstalled tor 6.0.8. When i attempt to connect on the Which of the following best describes your situation screen, it took about 10 minutes to load halfway and again, never finished; just sits on the connecting to the tor network screen/Loading relay information.

I checked similar posts and couldn't find an exact answer. My computer has the right time, but if there is a log or any other useful information I can post to help diagnose this, I'll be happy to do so. Thanks.

Comment: The current version of TBB is 6.5.1, see https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en Could you try downloading and using this? Does it work for you?

Comment: Logs should be available from the screen where it shows it trying to connect, there is a button marked 'copy tor log to clipboard' otherwise it's under the onion menu (tor button) -> network settings

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Firefox 40.0.2 has been considered unsupported since 2015-08-27 when 40.0.3 was released. There have been dozens of critical security issues since then. Firefox 43b9 isn't much better either. Based on the security issues fixed in the meantime, I recommend you consider your system compromised. Out of curiosity, what prompted you to install this version rather than the current 45.8.0 ESR or 52.0.1?

As mentioned by in the comment above, please try the current Tor Browser version. Version 6.0.8 no longer supported and should no longer be used.